# Vue.js concatenate string in v-text

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I am trying to concatenate string inside v-text directive. Simple example:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="obj in frameworks"> {{ obj.name }} has {{ obj.vite }} users
    <button v-on:click="removeFw(obj)" v-show="mode == 'edit'">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works fine. Now, instead of using the text interpolation if i use v-text like below, i still get the text showing up, but the `Delete` buttons disappear, regardless of the value of the `mode` property. These buttons should be visible if user clicks the `edit` button.

```
 <ul>
    <li v-for="obj in frameworks" v-text="`${obj.name} has ${obj.votes} users`">
     <button v-on:click="removeFw(obj)" v-show="mode == 'edit'">Delete</button>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/30a6edvs/

Can anyone please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using v-text will replace inner text/html of the element and thus you cannot see the delete button inside that. So you have to do as your first example code.

Comment: This makes sense! v-text actually replaces everything that is there between the opening and closing tags of the element on which it is being used. So in my case, it is removing the buttons as well..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually changing the elements and setting the text.

So if you want the text and also button then your first method ([`Mustache` `interpolations`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text)) is the way

> If you need to update the part of
> `textContent`, you should use {{ Mustache }} interpolations.

[Details](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text)